# Does C# have a way to mimic Software Transactional Memory, on a small scale?

Tags: c#, .net

Does C# have a way to temporarily change the value of a variable in a specific scope and revert it back automatically at the end of the scope/block?

For instance (not real code):

```
bool UpdateOnInput = true;

using (UpdateOnInput = false)
{
    //Doing my changes without notifying anyone
    Console.WriteLine (UpdateOnInput) // prints false
}
//UpdateOnInput is true again.
```

EDIT:

The reason I want the above is because I don't want to do this:

```
UpdateOnInput = false

//Doing my changes without notifying anyone
Console.WriteLine (UpdateOnInput) // prints false

UpdateOnInput = true
```

Comment: Software Transactional Memory?

Comment: sad to see that you have a very good rep and still posting the entire question as the title.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what specifically you need this construct for? This happens for variables passed by value automatically such as when making function calls, but I am not sure that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well that's how people told me to do. How else I can word it in 2 ways?

Comment: GrayWizardx, how do you mean it's automatic for function calls? You mean that fact that you can change them in the method body?

Comment: I had the same thought as GrayWizardx, hopefully my answer clarifies what he means.

Comment: I've done this in a macro in boo... all we need is a semantically safe macro system for C# and you're done :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this directly. There are a few different schools of thought on how to do this sort of thing.  Compare and contrast these two:

```
originalState = GetState();
SetState(newState);
DoSomething();
SetState(originalState);
```

vs

```
originalState = GetState();
SetState(newState);
try
{
    DoSomething();
}
finally
{
    SetState(originalState);
}
```

Many people will tell you that the latter is "safer".

It ain't necessarily so.

The difference between the two is of course the the latter restores the state even if DoSomething() throws an exception. Is that *better* than keeping the state mutated in an exception scenario?  **What makes it better?**  You have an unexpected, unhandled exception reporting that something *awful* and *unexpected* has happened. Your internal state could be completely inconsistent and arbitrarily messed up; no one knows what might have been happening at the point of the exception. All we know is that DoSomething probably was trying to do something to the mutated state.

Is it really the right thing to do in the scenario where something terrible and unknown has happened to keep on stirring that particular pot and trying to mutate the state that just caused an exception *again*?

Sometimes that is going to be the right thing to do, and sometimes its going to make matters worse. Which scenario you're actually in depends on what exactly the code is doing, so think carefully about what the right thing to do is before just blindly choosing one or the other.

Frankly, I would rather solve the problem by not getting into the situation in the first place. Our existing compiler design uses this design pattern, and frankly, it is freakin' irritating. In the existing C# compiler the error reporting mechanism is "side effecting". That is, when part of the compiler gets an error, it calls the error reporting mechanism which then displays the error to the user.

This is a major problem for lambda binding. If you have:

```
void M(Func<int, int> f) {}
void M(Func<string, int> f) {}
...
M(x=>x.Length);
```

then the way this works is we try to bind

```
M((int x)=>{return x.Length;});
```

and

```
M((string x)=>{return x.Length;});
```

and we see which one, if any, gives us an error. In this case, the former gives an error, the latter compiles without error, so this is a legal lambda conversion and overload resolution succeeds. *What do we do with the error?*  We cannot report it to the user because this program is error free!

Therefore what we do when we bind the body of a lambda is exactly what you say: we tell the error reporter "don't report your errors to the user; save them in this buffer over here instead". Then we bind the lambda, restore the error reporter to its earlier state, and look at the contents of the error buffer.

We could avoid this problem entirely by changing the expression analyzer so that it returned the errors along with the result, rather than making errors a state-related side effect. Then the need for mutation of the error reporting state goes away entirely and we don't even have to worry about it.

So I would encourage you to revisit your design. Is there a way you can make the operation you are performing not dependent upon the state you are mutating?  If so, then do that, and then you don't need to worry about how to restore the mutated state.

(And of course in our case we *do* want to restore the state upon an exception. If something inside the compiler throws during lambda binding, we want to be able to report that to the user! We don't want the error reporter to stay in the "suppress reporting errors" state.)

Comment: The way I see it, if the exception is expected, therefore handled, the `finally` block should run and wind back any state changes to restore a known good state. If the exception is unexpected, it should not be handled, and the program should terminate without running finally blocks: this can be arranged by handling `AppDomain.UnhandledException` and calling `Environment.FailFast`. With this approach, `finally` blocks are always a no-brainer: they can be safely written to unwind state as required. The controlling factor over whether they execute is whether an exception is ever caught or not.

Comment: One day someone should try to reverse engineer the C# compiler from the little nuggets you mention here and on your blog...

Comment: Thanks Eric. In my example, say for a system that detects some change, and the stuff the method does should not be detected, how would you design it that the method doesn't rely on that state that's used by the change_detection_system? Does it require a very different thinking?

Answer (score 12):

No, but it is pretty simple to just do this:

```
bool UpdateOnTrue = true;

// ....

bool temp = UpdateOnTrue;
try
{
    UpdateOnTrue = false;
    //  do stuff
}
finally
{
    UpdateOnTrue = temp; 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
public void WithAssignment<T>(ref T var, T val, Action action)
{
    T original = var;
    var = val;
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    finally
    {
        var = original;
    }
}
```

Now you can say:

```
bool flag = false;

WithAssignment(ref flag, true, () =>
{
    // flag is true during this block
});

// flag is false again
```

Comment: +1 Exactly what I would have written. Perfect combination of `ref` and lambda-expressions.

Answer (score 5):

No, you have to do it manually with a try/finally block. I dare say you *could* write an `IDisposable` implementation which would do something hacky in conjunction with lambda expressions, but I suspect a try/finally block is simpler (and doesn't [abuse the `using` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101524/is-it-abusive-to-use-idisposable-and-using-as-a-means-for-getting-scoped-behav/2103158#2103158)).

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you really want

```
Stack<bool>
```

Comment: You could go one step more and put the code in a function and pass the variable as a parameter, then the stack is managed for you without ever thinking about it.

Comment: This is oversimplifying rather a lot. The variable being set may be a field rather than a local variable, the point being to stop re-entrance into the code block. Sometimes it's okay to ignore a message (e.g. a mouse move event) due to an object being "in use" when the message arrived.

Answer (score 1):

No , there is not standard way, you should implement it manually. [Generic implementation of IEditableObject via TypeDescriptor and Reflection](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ieditableobject_wrapper.aspx) can be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

Canned... I doubt it.  Given your example is a simple use of a temporary bool value I'm assuming you've got something wacky in mind :-)  You can implement some kind of Stack stucture:

1) Push old value onto stack

2) Load new value

3) Do Stuff

4) Pop from stack and replace used value.

Rough (AKA Untested) example (Can't look up stack syntax right now)

```
bool CurrentValue = true;
Stack<bool> Storage= new Stack<bool>

Storage.Push(CurrentValue);
CurrentValue=false;
DoStuff();
CurrentValue = Storage.Pop();  
//Continue
```

Comment: Thanks but by old value you mean the false or true in my example? Can you please show this in code?

Comment: @Joan Venge  Added a rough code example to show what I'm talking about

Answer (score 1):

You should refactor your code to use a separate function, like so:

```
bool b = GetSomeValue();
DoSomething(ModifyValue(b));
//b still has the original value.
```

For this to work for a reference type, you need to copy it before messing with it:

```
ICloneable obj = GetSomeValue();
DoSomething(ModifyValue(obj.Clone()));
//obj still has the original value.
```

It's hard to write correct code when the values of your variables change around a lot. Strive to have as few reassignments in your code as possible.