# Implementing RAII in C#

Tags: c#, raii

I have an InfoPath form which I need to conditionally disable it's OnChange events. Since it's not possible to bind the event handlers after the form has loaded, I'm forced to rely on a global counter which indicates whether an OnChange event should be executed.
Inside each OnChange event, I check whether SuppressEventsCount == 0 before performing any actions.
To suppress events during the execution of some function or another, I simply set SuppressEventsCount++, and -- again when the function exits. The biggest problem with doing this is that it's not exception safe. So I had the bright idea to wrap the SuppressEvents counter in a class which implements iDisposable

```
using(SuppressEvents s = new SuppressEvents()){
   // OnChange events fired here are ignored
} // OnChange events enabled again
```

This is working, but it's still not as ideal as a c++ solution which doesn't require the use of the "using" directive at all.

Is there some way to either:

1. Trigger a destructor or some function the moment an object goes out of scope, OR
2. Prevent the SuppressEvents object from being initialised outside of a "using" directive entirely

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2101524/6345 (Is it abusive to use IDisposable and “using” as a means for getting “scoped behavior” for exception safety?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In relation to question 2, it might be possible to get around it by providing a different interface to consumers of the code. Instead of providing a public class that implements `IDisposable`, and hoping they wrap it in a `using`, you could provide a static method that takes a function to execute in a "suppressed" context:

```
public static class EventSuppressor {
    public void Suppress(Action action) {
        using (var s = new SuppressActions()) {
            action();
        }
    }

    private class SuppressActions : IDisposable {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then consumers can use this as follows:

```
EventSuppressor.Suppress(() => {
    // OnChange events fired here are ignored
}) // OnChange events enabled again
```

Of course, you have to work out whether this design is appropriate, as this will result in extra function calls, compiler generated classes and closures etc.

Answer (score 13):

No and no. `using` is the closest you can get to RAII (more accurately, we are talking about the resource release that follows a RAII-idiom object being destructed).

To answer your points more directly:

1. `IDisposable` (and by extension `using`) was created exactly because there is no way to do that in .NET.
2. `using` is syntactic sugar that gets compiled as `try`/`finally` and only requires that the object is `IDisposable`, so you cannot distinguish between usage inside a `using` statement and out of it.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your two questions:

1. No, there is not, Garbage Collection in .NET is not deterministic in nature
2. No, you can not, the `using` clause gets translated into a try/finally block type of code, and in any case you cannot detect that it is constructed from any of those two constructs, compared to outside

Answer (score 1):

If you can move from C# to C++.NET (still 100% .NET if compiled with clr:safe), then you can use msclr::auto_handle which acts just like a smart pointer such as auto_ptr etc...

What it really does behind the scene in IL is a bunch of try/fault commands but this is all completely invisible to the developer and user. The whole process is simply better IMO.