# Take 2: Is it abusive to use IDisposable and “using” as a means for getting “scoped behavior”?

Tags: c#, exception, anti-patterns

TL;DR -- Is it ever appropriate to execute business logic in IDisposable.Dispose?

In my search for an answer, I read through the question: [Is it abusive to use IDisposable and "using" as a means for getting "scoped behavior" for exception safety?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101524/is-it-abusive-to-use-idisposable-and-using-as-a-means-for-getting-scoped-beha) It came very close to addressing this issue, but I'd like to attack it dead on. I recently encountered some code that looked like this:

```
class Foo : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        ExecuteSomeBusinessBehavior();
        NormalCleanup();
    }
}
```

and is used in a context such as:

```
try 
{
    using (var myFoo = new Foo())
    {
        DoStuff();
        foo.DoSomethingFooey();
        ...
        DoSomethingElse();
        Etc();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle stuff
}
```

Upon seeing this code I immediately began to itch. Here's what I see when I look at this code:

First, looking at just the usage context, it's not remotely apparent that actual business logic, not just cleanup code, will be executed when the code leaves the using scope.

Second, if any of the code within the "using" scope throws an exception, the business logic in the Dispose method will still execute and does so before the Try/Catch can handle the exception.

My questions to the StackOverflow community are these: Does it ever make sense to put business logic in the IDisposable.Dispose method? Is there a pattern that achieves similar results without making me itch?

Comment: Please do not use Dispose for business logic. It's a mechanism to clean up unmanaged resources; use it for its by-design purpose.

Comment: @EricLippert: would `TransactionScope` be the exception which proves the rule?

Comment: @user7116: I note that many people do not realize that in that saying, "proves" means "subjects to testing".  Hence the expression "proving ground" for a weapons test range. Yes, that is an exception which *proves* -- subjects to testing -- the rule. I'd consider the result of that test to be that the usage is somewhat suspicious; why doesn't the call to `Complete` do the commit, and the `Dispose` simply close the connection? I note also that the documentation contradicts itself as to whether the `Complete` or the `Dispose` does the commit.

Comment: @EricLippert: I only asked because I've found it to be a poor usage of the pattern in practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real meaning of `IDisposable` is that an object knows of something, somewhere which has been put into a state that should be cleaned up, and it has the information and impetus necessary to perform such cleanup.  Although the most common "states" associated with `IDisposable` are things like files being open, unmanaged graphic objects being allocated, etc. those are only examples of uses, and not a definition of "proper" use.

The biggest issue to consider when using `IDisposable` and `using` for scoped behavior is that there is no way for the `Dispose` method to distinguish scenarios where an exception is thrown from a `using` block from those where it exits normally.  This is unfortunate, since there are many situations where it would be useful to have scoped behavior which was guaranteed to have one of two exit paths depending upon whether the exit was normal or abnormal.

Consider, for example, a reader-writer lock object with a method that returns an `IDisposable` "token" when the lock is acquired.  It would be nice to say:

```
using (writeToken = myLock.AcquireForWrite())
{
   ... Code to execute while holding write lock
}
```

If one were to manually code the acquisition and release of the lock without a try/catch or try/finally lock, an exception thrown while the lock was held would cause any code that was waiting on the lock to wait forever.  That is a bad thing.  Employing a `using` block as shown above will cause the lock to be released when the block exits, whether normally or via exception.  Unfortunately, that may *also* be a bad thing.

If an unexpected exception is thrown while a write-lock is held, the safest course of behavior would be to *invalidate* the lock so that any present or future attempt to acquire the lock will throw an immediate exception.  If the program cannot usefully proceed without the locked resource being usable, such behavior would cause it to shut down quickly.  If it can proceed e.g. by switching to some alternate resource, invalidating the resource will allow it to get on with that much more effectively than would leaving the lock uselessly acquired.  Unfortunately, I don't know of any nice pattern to accomplish that.  One could do something like:

```
using (writeToken = myLock.AcquireForWrite())
{
   ... Code to execute while holding write lock
   writeToken.SignalSuccess();
}
```

and have the `Dispose` method invalidate the token if it's called before success has been signaled, but an accidental failure to signal the success could cause the resource to become invalid without offering indication as to where or why that happened.  Having the `Dispose` method throw an exception if code exits a `using` block normally without calling `SignalSuccess` might be good, except that throwing an exception when it exits because of some other exception would destroy all information about that other exception, and there's no way `Dispose` can tell which method applies.

Given those considerations, I think the best bet is probably to use something like:

```
using (lockToken = myLock.CreateToken())
{
   lockToken.AcquireWrite(Describe how object may be invalid if this code fails");
   ... Code to execute while holding write lock
   lockToken.ReleaseWrite();
}
```

If code exits without calling `ReleaseWrite`, other threads that try to acquire the lock will receive exceptions that include the indicated message.  Failure to properly manually pair the `AcquireWrite` and `ReleaseWrite` will leave the locked object unusable, but not leave other code waiting for it to become usable.  Note that an unbalanced `AcquireRead` would not have to invalidate the lock object, since code inside the read would never put the object into an invalid state.

Comment: From the very description of [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx): "Defines a method to *release allocated resources*."  The lock cleanup is acceptable (if a rather convoluted example), but "cleanup" that involves doing real work other than releasing resources is outside of its scope.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to merge `CreateToken()` and `AcquireWrite()` into a single method?

Comment: @svick: IMHO, since `ReleaseWrite` needs to be explicitly stated to avoid releasing the lock when it should be invalidated, it should be "visibly" balanced with an `AcquireRead` that's not part of a `using` statement.  Further, even if code acquires and releases the lock multiple times, only one `using` is needed.  Actually, even if one were using multiple locks, one might use a single using statement with one lock-token manager, and have `AcquireWrite`, `ReleaseWrite`, etc. accept lock objects to be acquired or released (keeping a list of unbalanced acquisitions which...

Comment: ...would need to be invalidated in case of `Dispose`).  It really would be nice if one could safely employ a `using` construct, but I'm not sure of any really good way of doing that.  One could achieve proper semantics with an interator and `foreach`, but it would probably look too weird to really be justifiable [`foreach (var token in myLock.AcquireWriteTokenToken()) {...code goes here...}`]

Comment: @supercat The balancing argument makes sense. Your `foreach` idea is deviously clever and also very confusing on several levels. Yeah, it works and is concise, but if I ever saw that in real code, I would reach for my pitchfork :-)

Comment: @svick: The behavior of `foreach` clearly demonstrates that it's possible to coax the compiler into generating proper semantics.  Too bad there's no way to make it not look hideous.

Answer (score 5):

(Sorry, this is more of a comment, but it exceeds the comment length limit.)

Actually, there is an example in the .NET framework where IDisposable is used to create a scope and *do useful work* when disposing: **TransactionScope**.

To quote from [TransactionScope.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.dispose.aspx):

> Calling this method marks the end of the transaction scope. If the TransactionScope object created the transaction and Complete was called on the scope, the TransactionScope object attempts to commit the transaction when this method is called.

If you decide to take that route, I would suggest that

- you make it blatantly obvious that your object *creates a scope*, e.g., by calling it `FooScope` instead of `Foo` and
- you think very hard about what should happen when an exception causes the code to leave your scope. In `TransactionScope`, the pattern of calling `Complete` at the end of the block ensures that `Dispose` can distinguish between the two cases.

Comment: +1. We've done something similar for session scopes when wrapping third-party libraries that require logging on / logging off.

Answer (score 2):

Business logic code should never be written in any circumstances to Dispose method reason is, you are relying on a unreliable path. What if user does not call your dispose method? You missed to call a complete functionality ? What if there was an exception thrown in the method call of your dispose method? And why would you perform a business operation when user is asking to dispose the object itself. So logically, technically it should not be done.

Comment: +1 - doing this also obscures the logic flow for the reader of the code.

Comment: Normally if you do go this route you have a normal command like `.Close()` and the only action you have your `.Dispose()` do is call `.Close()` upon being disposed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently reading [Introduction to Rx](http://introtorx.com/), by [Lee Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/393615/lee-campbell), and it has a chapter called `IDisposable`, where he explicitly advocates taking advantage of the integration with the `using` construct, in order to "create transient scope".

Some key quotations from that chapter:

> "If we consider that we can use the IDisposable interface to effectively create a scope, you can create some fun little classes to leverage this."
>
> (...see examples below...)
>
> "So we can see that you can use the IDisposable interface for more than just common use of deterministically releasing unmanaged resources. It is a useful tool for managing lifetime or scope of anything; from a stopwatch timer, to the current color of the console text, to the subscription to a sequence of notifications.
>
> The Rx library itself adopts this liberal usage of the IDisposable interface and introduces several of its own custom implementations:
>
> - BooleanDisposable
> - CancellationDisposable
> - CompositeDisposable
> - ContextDisposable
> - MultipleAssignmentDisposable
> - RefCountDisposable
> - ScheduledDisposable
> - SerialDisposable
> - SingleAssignmentDisposable"

He gives two fun little examples, indeed:

---

Example 1 - Timing code execution. "This handy little class allows you to create scope and measure the time certain sections of your code base take to run."

```
public class TimeIt : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly Stopwatch _watch;

    public TimeIt(‌string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        _watch = Stopwatch‌.StartNew(‌);
    }

    public void Dispose(‌)
    {
        _watch‌.Stop(‌);
        Console‌.WriteLine(‌"{0} took {1}", _name, _watch‌.Elapsed);
    }
}

using (‌new TimeIt(‌"Outer scope"))
{
    using (‌new TimeIt(‌"Inner scope A"))
    {
        DoSomeWork(‌"A");
    }

    using (‌new TimeIt(‌"Inner scope B"))
    {
        DoSomeWork(‌"B");
    }

    Cleanup(‌);
}
```

Output:

```
Inner scope A took 00:00:01.0000000
Inner scope B took 00:00:01.5000000
Outer scope took 00:00:02.8000000
```

---

Example 2 - Temporarily changing console text color

```
//Creates a scope for a console foreground color‌. When disposed, will return to 
//  the previous Console‌.ForegroundColor

public class ConsoleColor : IDisposable
{
    private readonly System‌.ConsoleColor _previousColor;
    
    public ConsoleColor(‌System‌.ConsoleColor color)
    {
        _previousColor = Console‌.ForegroundColor;
        Console‌.ForegroundColor = color;
    }

    public void Dispose(‌)
    {
        Console‌.ForegroundColor = _previousColor;
    }
}


Console‌.WriteLine(‌"Normal color");

using (‌new ConsoleColor(‌System‌.ConsoleColor‌.Red))
{
    Console‌.WriteLine(‌"Now I am Red");

    using (‌new ConsoleColor(‌System‌.ConsoleColor‌.Green))
    {
        Console‌.WriteLine(‌"Now I am Green");
    }

    Console‌.WriteLine(‌"and back to Red");
}
```

Output:

```
Normal color
Now I am Red
Now I am Green
and back to Red
```