# Is abusing IDisposable to benefit from "using" statements considered harmful?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

The purpose of the interface `IDisposable` is to release unmanaged resources in an orderly fashion. It goes hand in hand with the `using` keyword that defines a scope after the end of which the resource in question is disposed of.

Because this meachnism is so neat, I've been repeatedly tempted to have classes implement `IDisposable` to be able to abuse this mechanism in ways it's not intended for. For example, one could implement classes to handle nested contexts  like this:

```
class Context : IDisposable
{
    // Put a new context onto the stack
    public static void PushContext() { ... }

    // Remove the topmost context from the stack
    private static void PopContext() { ... }

    // Retrieve the topmost context
    public static Context CurrentContext { get { ... } }

    // Disposing of a context pops it from the stack
    public void Dispose()
    {
        PopContext();
    }
}
```

Usage in calling code might look like this:

```
using (Context.PushContext())
{
   DoContextualStuff(Context.CurrentContext);
} // <-- the context is popped upon leaving the block
```

(Please note that this is just an example and not to the topic of this question.)

The fact that `Dispose()` is called upon leaving the scope of the `using` statement can also be exploited to implement all sorts of things that depend on scope, e.g. timers. This could also be handled by using a `try ... finally` construct, but in that case the programmer would have to manually call some method (e.g. `Context.Pop`), which the `using` construct could do for thon.

This usage of `IDisposable` does not coincide with its intended purpose [as stated in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.idisposable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), yet the temptation persists.

Are there concrete reasons to illustrate that this is a bad idea and dispell my fantasies forever, for example complications with garbage collection, exception handling, etc. Or should I go ahead and indulge myself by abusing this language concept in this way?

Comment: There are lot other concepts that could be misused, the above is one of them, the only thing is **readability**, remember your code should be clear/readable and maintainable by other developers.

Comment: I agree with Habib. Always think about the poor bastard that will have to work with your code 18 months from now. there's a good chance that bastard will be you :-)

Comment: It's a subjective question, but you could note that the ASP.NET MVC framework abuses IDisposable in this way - for example `FormExtensions.BeginForm`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it abusive to use IDisposable and "using" as a means for getting "scoped behavior" for exception safety?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101524/is-it-abusive-to-use-idisposable-and-using-as-a-means-for-getting-scoped-beha)

Comment: I have edited the question make it clearer that I'm not looking for opinions (I already have one: "This works great!"), but for concrete reasons why this usage could/will lead to issues.

Comment: I will also check the linked question to see if mine can be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So in asp.net MVC views, we see the following construct:

```
using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    //some form elements
}
```

An abuse? Microsoft says no (indirectly).

If you have a construct that ***requires*** something to happen once you're done with it, `IDisposable` can often work out quite nicely. I've done this more than once.

Comment: Similar with transaction scope.

Comment: Agreed with spender. It's used by Microsoft in ways that don't always release resources, so I think it's "allowed." That being said, readability should be your concern. I think the `BeginForm` is clear; Popping from a list, not so much.

Comment: If the `using` line contains "Push", I'd say popping is pretty obvious.

Comment: @Medinoc Sure, just as if it contains `Begin` I'd say `End` is pretty obvious... But in both cases, easy to forget. The using construct simply increases your chance of falling into the pit of success.

Comment: Why not just use a `try/finally`?  It's just as readable.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway `using` is already syntactic sugar around `try/finally`, but with a handy standard interface. Without `IDisposable`, the caller needs to know how to clean-up, whereas `using` puts the burden on the creator.

Answer (score 3):

"Is it an abuse of the `IDisposable` interface to use it this way"? Probably.

Does using `using` as a purely "scoping" construct make for more obvious intent and better readability of code? Certainly.

The latter trumps the former for me, so I say use it.

Comment: Why not just use `try/finally`? It's just as readable.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway in this scenario I'd disagree, mainly because (a) in this case you'd end up with an empty `finally` and (b) IMO because `using` declares scoped intent far more clearly than `try/finally`. To me, `using` says "I am doing something with this object and want it to go away afterwards"; `try/finally` says "I may get an exception here and I want to handle it".

Comment: I would have to disagree with part of your statement.  `try/finally` (with no catch clause) does not imply anything about exceptions.  The finally would have whatever necessary cleanup code and says "I want to do the follow and and then finally clean up".  At least that's how I would read it.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly wouldn't be the first one to 'abuse' IDisposable in that way. Probably my favorite use of it is in timers, as the [StatsD.NET client](https://github.com/lukevenediger/statsd-csharp-client#quickstart) demonstrates:

```
using StatsdClient;
...
using (statsd.LogTiming( "site.db.fetchReport" ))
{
  // do some work
}
// At this point your latency has been sent to the server
```

In fact, I'm pretty sure Microsoft themselves use it in some libraries. My rule of thumb would be - if it improves readbility, go for it.

Comment: Why not just use `try/finally`? It's just as readable.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway The point here is to time the operation within the using block, not protecting against exceptions. You can read it as `using myTimer, do ...` and, by doing so, condense what would otherwise be three lines of code (timer.Start, timer.Stop, timer.SendToServer) into something (arguably) more readable.