# Implementing a very basic IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I would like to implement a very simple `IDisposable`.
The whole idea is to measure the execution time of my methods which they all return a `MethodResult`. e.g.

```
public class MethodResult : IDisposable
{
    private Stopwatch _StopWatch;
    public MethodResult()
    {
        _StopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        _StopWatch.Start();
    }
    public object Result { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ExecutionTime { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _StopWatch.Stop();
        ExecutionTime = _StopWatch.Elapsed;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
static MethodResult TestMehodResult()
{
    using (var result = new MethodResult())
    {
        result.Result = 666;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return result;
    }
}
```

My question is really simple: is implementing only `Dispose()` method is sufficient for this case, or should I implement the entire [`Dispose` pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in my class?
There are no resources to free in my class.

Bonus question: Is there a better pattern to measure execution time of a method instead of using an `IDisposable` like I did?

Sorry if this question is dumb. I'm really new to .net
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it is not a good way. It will function as you want, but it will be confusing for everyone. Disposing an object is supposed to render it useless, but you are "disposing" it right before returning. Compare this to [another abuse of IDisposable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2101524/11683) which feels much more justified.

Comment: The longer form (standard Microsoft) pattern has two main advantages. a) It handles unmanaged resources. b) It handles inheritance. You don't need either, so your form is fine for your purposes. _@GSerg has rightly questioned whether you should use `Dispose` - my comments are purely comparing your code to the longer form - I am not saying you should or shouldn't use `Dispose`._

Comment: @mjwills The class is [not sealed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/898867/11683), so a longer form is still required.

Comment: Rather than `return result;` consider `return result.SomeProperty;` where `SomeProperty` provides the necessary data. This allows you to use the `Dispose` pattern, but deals with @GSerg's primary (and valid) concern.

Comment: `so a longer form is still required.` In the theoretical sense, yes. In the practical sense, no. But sure, adding `sealed` to the class would be clearer.

Comment: @mjwills, Sorry for being stupid but I really don't understand what @GSerg is saying. `"Disposing an object is supposed to render it useless, but you are "disposing" it right before returning"`. And I need to result result becoause it holds the entire class I need for my methods (it also contains other properties such as `Error` object etc...)

Comment: It is odd (not illegal, but odd / non-standard) to have an object where you continue to use it after being disposed. But that is exactly what you are doing - your `TestMehodResult` method `Dispose`s it, then returns it. It will _work_, but it is odd. The solution is to separate the current class into two classes. The new class will have the `Result` and `ExecutionTime` properties. Then use `return result.YourNewPropertyWhichPopulatesYourNewClass;` rather than `return result;`.

Comment: @mjwills, Ahhh. thanks. now I see what you are both saying. never thought of that. I only did this because it looked like a "nice", fast and readable way to handle my (already existing many many) methods. I suppose I could use a `try`/`finally result.Finalize()` before returning but that looks kinda ugly to me. I also did not understand the issue with the `sealed` keyword. in practice `MethodResult ` is a base class for descendants (`MethodResult <T>`) so I guess it can not be sealed?

Comment: @mjwills, You mentioned that in the longer form `It handles inheritance.` I just tested with a descendant  class where `public class MethodResult2 : MethodResult` changing the result of my method to return `MethodResult2` worked just fine. the `Dispose` method was invoked. so I don't see an issue with inheritance here.

Comment: Though the way of using disposables like this is quite unusual, it wouldn't be a problem (I also created a similar [Profiler](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#performance-measurement) once). What is confusing here is this `MethodResult` class, which is actually a measurement scope rather than a result of a method. What if the method is void? Or if not a single method is measured? I called it `MeasureOperation` but it is not exposed as a public type. Feel free to use or investigate the source under the link.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg, Thanks. I see what you mean. in *my case* there are no void methods. they are actually  all web service methods for which *always* return `MethodResult<T>`. I would like the response (result) to contain `ExecutionTime` (but I guess that is irrelevant to the actual question?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stay true to the concept of scope, you can inject your result in the `IDisposable`'s constructor. Using an interface to keep things flexible. I'm surprised nobody mentioned the loss of type safety in your method, I'd definitely add the generic type parameter to the base `MethodResult` class (as you mention it to be in the comments).

```cs
public interface ITimed
{
    TimeSpan ExecutionTime { get; set; }
}

public class MethodResult<T> : ITimed
{
    public T Result { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ExecutionTime { get; set; }
}

public class MethodTimer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Stopwatch _StopWatch;
    private ITimed _result;

    public MethodTimer(ITimed result)
    {
        _result = result;
        _StopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        _StopWatch.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _StopWatch.Stop();
        _result.ExecutionTime = _StopWatch.Elapsed;
        _result = null;
    }
}
```

Usage

```cs
static MethodResult<int> TestMehodResult()
{
    var timedResult = new MethodResult<int>();

    using (var timer = new MethodTimer(timedResult))
    {
        timedResult.Result = 666;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    return timedResult;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. this is basically what I started doing after reading @GyörgyKőszeg comment. why the `_result = null` in the `MethodTimer.Dispose()` method needed? wouldn't it set the result to null?

Comment: @zig The result will outlive the timer, so we dispose (no pun intended) of its reference to mark the timer for garbage collection as soon as possible.

Comment: Setting it to null isn’t necessary and has no benefit here. If you use the using pattern, the `timer` instance will go out of scope at the same time Dispose is called, so the GC already knows that `timer` can be freed and doesn’t hold a reference to `_result` anymore.

Comment: `Setting it to null isn’t necessary and has no benefit here.` It has benefit if `MethodTimer` has a longish lifetime (e.g. not scoped within a function). I agree with @Funk's implementation here - there is no _downside_ of setting it to `null`. It often won't help, but it _sometimes_ will.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's fine, but I'd probably advise "sealing" the class; there can be no question over whether it needs a more complex `virtual Dispose(bool)` API, finalizer support, if you simply declare it as:

```cs
public sealed class MethodResult : IDisposable
```

because now:

- it *can't* be subclassed, so you know you don't need to deal with polymorphism
- it *doesn't* have a finalizer, and you know that a subclass doesn't

So: very explicit and obvious.

Comment: But what if it needs to be sub-classed but has no resources to free? in my test I see that the Dispose() is being invoked just fine in sub-classed descendant.

Comment: @zig if it can be subclassed **by external types**, then the base class **doesn't know** that there are no resources - managed or unmanaged - to free (it shouldn't know much about the derived classes). In that case, I **would** use the `protected virtual Dispose(bool disposing)` approach. If it can only be subclassed by things *in your control* (i.e. it is an `internal` type or has only `internal` constructors): then sure, you can cheat and use the extra knowledge that you have